# I am trying to implement a count function in Python, without using len()

Tags: python, recursion, methods, count, iteration

```
def compute(arr, size):
  if not arr:
    return size
  else:
    compute(arr[1:], size+1)

def count(sequence):
  result = compute(sequence, 0)
  return result

array = [i for i in range(1, 101)]
print(count(array))
```

1. I am trying to build my own custom method of count

My intention is not to reinvent the wheel but to understand better about recursion and iteration

2. I have a compute a compute method that slices the array in every call
   and increments the size variable. When the array becomes empty , it returns the size.

but I am getting the result as `None`. Please let me know if I am doing something wrong here

Comment: You need to add `return compute(arr[1:], size+1)`

Comment: Thanks abccd, that was silly of me :)